How can I speed up a GIF animation by several orders of magnitude to create a persistence of vision effect?
I have a GIF animation consisting of 51 frames, generated by mathematical software (of a deforming curve).  It plays back by default at 10 FPS, for a duration of 5.1 seconds.
My goal is to play it in an infinite loop much faster than that, so that the different frames merge and create a persistence of vision effect.  This requires two things:

Making it an infinite loop, as described here.  Good.

Increasing the FPS by between 10x (510ms duration, will give POV of some of the animation) to 100x (51 ms duration, should give POV for full animation).  Here's the challenge.


Using simple GIF software, I can increase the frame rate by 5x or so.  Beyond that, GIF doesn't seem to support it.
I imagine MP4 can go higher, but not high enough.  So I assume I need to add intermediate frames in between.
It seems that can be done via ffmpeg -minterpolate. However, the options are bewildering, and I can't figure out which ones to use here.  Part of the challenge is that this is not "play this video back faster" but rather "turn these sequence of frames into a whole new creation, by animating them very fast in a loop" - doable, but not the default use case, and therefore harder to manage.
I've read this but am still confused.
How can I turn my GIF into an infinite loop, at very high FPS, with interpolated frames in between? Ideally I'd like to do this using ffmpeg.
Update
I've experimented with multiple ffmpeg options and can not get the full transform. If you'd like to try, the original GIF is here.  I'd like to keep it looping while speeding up its playback rate so that it has a total duration of 500ms, 100ms, or even 50ms (and then immediately loops again).


gif max fps 50? → ffmpeg -r 100 -i "mA2HVqDs.gif" -vf " minterpolate=50,split[g][p]; [p]palettegen[p]; [g][p]paletteuse" out.gif
